# Count with subquery, group_by and Left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery

I am struggeling for along time with this particular query. I am making a 'leaderboard' of users whom have added or received the most places to their guides.

My data model is as follows:

```
Users

uuid      id
string    first_name
bool      blogger

Guests

uuid      id

Tips (join model)

uuid     id
uuid     guide_id
uuid     place_id
integer  status
uuid     owner_id
string   owner_type

Guides

uuid     id 
uuid     user_id
string   name

Place
uuid     id
string   name
```

A user can add places (trough tips) to his/her guide. This same user can also receive places (tips) from other users to his/her guide. These tips can be accepted `tips.status = 1`.

What I want is the following:

first_name and count of all places added or accepted tips over all their guides, but not tips they have given to other users grouped by `users.blogger = 1`.

example:

```
Guest = true

you       40
user1     30
user2     25

Guest = false
user3     20
user4     15
user5      5
```

this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT tips.owner_id, tips.owner_type, count(tips.owner_id) AS places_count
FROM "tips" 
LEFT JOIN users on (owner_type ='User' AND users.id = owner_id) 
GROUP BY "tips"."owner_id", "tips"."owner_type" 
ORDER BY places_count DESC 
LIMIT 16
```

This query does return counts, but does not take received tips in regard and it also counts given tips to other users. I have a hunch that I need to use subqueries, firstly select all the guide id's from a given user and secondly 'simply' select a count of all tips where `guide_id = selected_guide_ids` AND `tips.status = 1`. Lastly group the results by `users.blogger = 1`

But how do I write this?

## Edit 1:

I have updated my original question with an additional `Guest` table (this is why I use `owner_type and owner_id instead` of `table_id`. And I've updated the user table with blogger (bool) on which I want to group the results.

Sample data:

```
Users

id      first_name      blogger
user1   Daniel          true
user2   Quassnoi        false
user3   vkp             true

Guests

id
guest_1
guest_2

Guides

id          user_id     name
guide_1     user_1      Bugers
guide_2     user_1      Cool places
guide_3     user_2      Amsterdam

Tips

id      guide_id    place_id    status  owner_id    owner_type
tip1    guide_1     place_1     1       user_1      User        # user_1 added place_1 to his own guide guide_1 (accepted)
tip2    guide_1     place_2     1       guest_1     Guest       # guest_1 suggested place_2 to user_1's guide guide_1 (accepted)
tip2    guide_1     place_2     0       guest_1     Guest       # guest_1 suggested place_2 to user_1's guide guide_1 (rejected)
tip_3   guide_2     place_1     1       user_2      User        # user_2 added place_1 to his own guide guide_3 (accepted)
tip_4   guide_2     place_2     1       user_2      User        # user_2 added place_2 to his own guide guide_3 (accepted)
tip_5   guide_2     place_3     1       user_1      User        # user_1 added place_3 to user_2's guide guide_2 (accepted)

Places

id      name
place1  burgerbar
place2  burgermeester
place_3 bbq shack
```

What my desired outcome is:

Note that tips given to other users don't count for the tip giver.

```
first_name  tips_count  blogger

Quassnoi    3           false (2 added by himself, 1 received from user_1)
Daniel      2           true (1 added by himself, 1 received from guest1. Note that the rejected tip does not count)
vkp         0           false
```

## Edit 2

I've altered Quassnoi's answer a little bit to this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users u
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT  g.user_id, COUNT(*) tips_count
    FROM    guides g
    JOIN    tips t
    ON      t.guide_id = g.id
    AND (t.owner_id = g.user_id AND t.status = 1)
    GROUP BY g.user_id
    ) g
ON      g.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY tips_count DESC
```

This however returns all the records where tips_count is NULL first. I want those to be 0 instead of NULL. How can I cast NULL tips_count to 0?

## Edit 3:

I've updated the query so that it only counts the tips where the guide_id is equal to the guide ids from the given user.

```
SELECT  *
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT  g.user_id, COUNT(*) tips_count
        FROM    guides g
        JOIN    tips t
        ON      t.guide_id = g.id
        AND     (t.guide_id = g.id AND t.status = 1)
        GROUP BY g.user_id
    ) g
ON g.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY tips_count DESC
```

Comment: sample data and the expected result would help answer the question.

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and there's nothing I can do without viewing the data.

Comment: how can you tell a guide belongs to a user?

Comment: You guys are right, I forgot to add the user_id on guides. I'll add some sample data and outcome data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it doesn't really matter who added/suggested a place. Once it is accepted (status 1) it belongs to the guide and thus to the guide's user. Hence:

```
select u.first_name, u.blogger, count(t.id)
from users u
left join guides g on g.user_id = u.id
left join tips t on t.guide_id = g.id and t.status = 1
group by u.id
order by count(t.id) desc;
```

Comment: You are right! This works like a charm (status is ambiguous so I added `t.status = 1`). Thanks!!

Comment: Ah, yes, I simply forgot the qualifier for status. Glad this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The way your schema is set up now, it's impossible to tell which guide belongs to which user.

Assuming there's a `guide.owner` you forgot to mention (or forgot to add), it would be:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    user u
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  g.owner, COUNT(*) cnt
                guide g
        JOIN    tips t
        ON      t.guide_id = g.id
                AND (t.owner_id = g.owner OR t.status = 1)
        GROUP BY
                g.owner
        ) g
ON      g.owner = u.id
```

Comment: I indeed forgot to add the user_id on guides. Thanks for your answer, I'm going to test it right away! I'll add some test data and outcome data to my question.

Comment: From might be useful here

Comment: I'm indeed getting a syntax error. I've altered your answer a little bit and added a `SORT BY tips_count DESC` however this returns alot of NULL tips_count where I want `tips_count` to be 0 instead of NULL

I've  updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for you time and effort Quassnoi